# WP CLI: critical error on your website

Tags: wp-cli

I want to use the cli to update my wordpress instance.
Unfortunately, I alwas get the "critical error on your website" message.
I've already checked the error.log of my webserver and also the debug.log of wordpress itself, but no error message apears there.
I've the following settings in my `wp-config` file

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

What can I do to find out what the error is. I've also already run a command with `--debug` at the end. But there I can see only the last successful command and after that, there is the "critical error" message again.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm not an expert in debugging Wordpress but I have always found it useful to specify the debug log file as "define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/tmp/wp-errors.log' );" Does your update work through the dashboard rather than the command line?

Comment: My error log is in wp-content is filled with other information as well. I still tried to specify the error log location as you suggested, but nothing changed. I don't get any errors. I was able to identify the plugin which is generating the error (by adding `--skip-plugins=XXX` until it worked).Everything works fine when I use the frontend of wordpress. I guess, that there is a problem with this in plugin in combination with WP CLI

Comment: You looked at the new log as specified by WP_DEBUG_LOG rather than looking at the old log, right? Which plugin did you identify as causing the issue. I'm glad you got it working, at least if you know which plugin it is you can contact the plugin creators.

Comment: yes, I've looked in the new log, but still no message. the plugin is https://tshirtecommerce.com/